# Carto JS no sublayer event response

Tags: carto, carto-js

I'm trying to create a custom infowindow based on cartojs sublayer.

I've tried many things, but through testing I think the issue is that the event is not being registered/recognized on any of my map sublayers.

My js is below:

```
var map;

function init(){
// set map options
var options = {
    zoom:13,
    center: [49.256, -123.1],
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: true,
    cartodb_logo: false,
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 18,
    maxBounds: [[53, -110], [44, -150]],
    attributionControl:true,
    };

// create the map object
map = new L.Map('map', options);

// sublayer container
var sublayers = [];

// create layer
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: 'jsalter',
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [
        //Baselayer
        {
        type: "http",
        urlTemplate: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        subdomains: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
        },

        //EUI
        {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM combiparcels",
        cartocss: '#combiparcels {\
                      [eui=null] {polygon-opacity: 0.0;polygon-fill: #fff;}\
                      [eui=0] {polygon-opacity: 0.0;polygon-fill: #fff;}\
                      [eui>1] {polygon-fill: #FEC428;}\
                      [eui>150] {polygon-fill: #F89541;}\
                      [eui>175] {polygon-fill: #E66B5C;}\
                      [eui>200] {polygon-fill: #CB4778;}\
                      [eui>225] {polygon-fill: #A92096;}\
                      [eui>250] {polygon-fill: #7E00A8;}\
                      [eui>275] {polygon-fill: #4C00A1;}\
                      [eui>300] {polygon-fill: #0D0287;}\
                      polygon-opacity: 1.0;\
                      polygon-gamma: 0.4;\
                      line-color: #FFF;\
                      line-width: 0;\
                      line-opacity: 1.0;\
                      line-comp-op: soft-light;\
                      [zoom>16]{line-width: 1.5;}\
                    }',
        },

        //GHG
        {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM combiparcels",
        cartocss: '#combiparcels {\
                      [ghg=null] {polygon-opacity: 0.0;polygon-fill: #fff;}\
                      [ghg=0] {polygon-opacity: 0.0;polygon-fill: #fff;}\
                      [ghg>=1] {polygon-fill: #FFFF00;}\
                      [ghg>5] {polygon-fill: #9EDB39;}\
                      [ghg>10] {polygon-fill: #4AC26D;}\
                      [ghg>50] {polygon-fill: #1FA288;}\
                      [ghg>100] {polygon-fill: #277F8E;}\
                      [ghg>200] {polygon-fill: #365C8D;}\
                      [ghg>300] {polygon-fill: #45317F;}\
                      [ghg>600] {polygon-fill: #440054;}\
                      polygon-opacity: 1.0;\
                      polygon-gamma: 0.4;\
                      line-color: #FFF;\
                      line-width: 0.0;\
                      line-opacity: 0.5;\
                      line-comp-op: soft-light;\
                      [zoom>16]{line-width: 1.5;}\
                    }'
        },

        //GHGi
        {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM combiparcels",
        cartocss: '#combiparcels {\
                        [ghgi=null] {polygon-opacity: 0.0;polygon-fill: #fff;}\
                        [ghgi>=0] {polygon-fill: #E1C7EC;}\
                        [ghgi>20] {polygon-fill: #B3B4D9;}\
                        [ghgi>25] {polygon-fill: #8FAED7;}\
                        [ghgi>30] {polygon-fill: #67A9CF;}\
                        [ghgi>35] {polygon-fill: #3690C0;}\
                        [ghgi>40] {polygon-fill: #02818A;}\
                        [ghgi>45] {polygon-fill: #016C59;}\
                        [ghgi>50] {polygon-fill: #014636;}\
                        polygon-opacity: 1.0;\
                      polygon-gamma: 0.4;\
                      line-color: #FFF;\
                      line-width: 0.0;\
                      line-opacity: 0.5;\
                      line-comp-op: soft-light;\
                      [zoom>16]{line-width: 1.5;}\
                    }'
        },

        //Labels
        {
        type: "http",
        urlTemplate: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        subdomains: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
        },

        //Buildings
        {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM ubc_bld_euis_hts ORDER BY ST_YMax(the_geom) DESC",
        cartocss: "#ubc_bld_euis_hts{\
                     polygon-opacity: 0.0;\
                      line-opacity:0;\
                      line-color: #FFFFFF;\
                      [bldg_ht>0]{[zoom < 14]{polygon-opacity: 0.0;line-opacity:0.0;}\
                    polygon-fill: #E5E2CF;\
                    polygon-opacity: 0.7;\
                    line-opacity:0.7;\
                    line-color: #B9B397;\
                    [zoom >14]::under{building-fill-opacity: 0.0;}\
                    [zoom >14]{\
                      polygon-fill:transparent;\
                      line-color: #B9B397;\
                      line-opacity:0.0;\
                      building-fill: #E5E2CF;\
                      building-fill-opacity: 0.9;\
                      building-height: [bldg_ht]*1.5;\
                      }\
                    }\
                }"
        },
        ],
    })
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer){

    var layer1 = layer.getSubLayer(1);
    layer1.show();        
    console.log(layer1); // show in the console

    var layer2 = layer.getSubLayer(2);
    layer2.hide();
    console.log(layer2); // show in the console

    var layer3 = layer.getSubLayer(3);
    layer3.hide();
    console.log(layer3); // show in the console 

    sublayers.push(layer1);
    sublayers.push(layer2);
    sublayers.push(layer3);

    layer1.on('featureClick', function(event, latlng, pos, data, layerIndex) {
        console.log("test event");
        console.log(data);
        });

    });

// button sublayer interaction
$("#eui").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selectedButton");
    $("#ghgi").removeClass("selectedButton");
    $("#ghg").removeClass("selectedButton");
    sublayers[0].show();
    sublayers[2].hide();
    sublayers[1].hide();
    $("#section03").css("background", '#E66B5C');
    $(".maptitle").html("Energy Use Intensity");
    document.getElementById("leg").src = "img/legEUI.svg";
    });

$("#ghgi").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selectedButton");
    $("#eui").removeClass("selectedButton");
    $("#ghg").removeClass("selectedButton");
    sublayers[0].hide();
    sublayers[2].show();
    sublayers[1].hide();
    $("#section03").css("background", '#3690C0');
    $(".maptitle").html("Greenhouse Gas Intensity");
    document.getElementById("leg").src = "img/legGHGi.svg";
    });

$("#ghg").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selectedButton");
    $("#eui").removeClass("selectedButton");
    $("#ghgi").removeClass("selectedButton");
    sublayers[0].hide();
    sublayers[2].hide();
    sublayers[1].show();
    $("#section03").css("background", '#4AC26D');
    $(".maptitle").html("Greenhouse Gas Emissions");
    document.getElementById("leg").src = "img/legGHG.svg";
    });
}
```

I cannot resolve why there is no interaction, at this stage I'm just trying to get the console to log the event so I know it is working.

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of redundant code there (where bugs can be hidden). But anyway to set sublayers interaction CARTO.js has `setInteraction(True)` method. Also, you would need to set the fields you want to be activated with `sublayer.setInteractivity('field_1, field_2...')`. [Here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods#cartodbcartodbsublayer) you have the link to CARTO.js sublayers method documentation.

In addition, you need to use [`sublayer.infowindow`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods#sublayerinfowindow) or [`cartodb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/ui-functions#cartodbvisvisaddinfowindowmap-layer-fields--options) methods joining the infowindow template with the sublayer/layer. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c) you have a working example.

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar. Sorry the js isn't pretty, I'm a js novice. I've set interaction and interactivity fields for the sublayer, but still no interaction is occurring. The map is buried deep within nested divs, could the css be the issue not allowing event triggers to pass through?

Comment: No idea what is happening. I recommend adding to your question [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the whole code. In doing so, we will be able to detect what is causing the problem.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the support @ramiroaznar. I've stripped back the code to the basic elements and still no interactivity. The JSFiddle is available @ https://jsfiddle.net/rory/g338njku/.

Comment: Please have a look at the second paragraph I have added to my answer. You miss a key block of code, after setting the interactivity to `true`, you need the methods that I have commented above.